# Spring Jars to download

Tags: spring

I am using below link for downloading spring jars.
http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/

I am confused with so many links.
Which link should i use to download the jar?
I am using a Windows machine and create a project directly through New Java  Project.

Comment: According to your knowledge, I strongly recommend you to use Spring Tool Suite (https://spring.io/tools), and then to use the Wizzard for a new "Spring Project" with template "Simple Spring Web Maven" or "Spring MVC Project" (or start with the Spring Boot Project by using the "Spring Starter Project" Wizzard)

Comment: use maven or gradle; developers aren't supposed to do dependency management manually, this is a waste of time. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management

Answer (score 19):

Please refer this url http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/ and Choose the which version Spring Jars you want.

[image]

Choose the spring-framework-X.X.X.RELEASE-dist.zip

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You should be using [this](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE-dist.zip) link to download spring jars. Other links in there are for checksum or documentation.

Comment: Thank You @SMA :)

Comment: The link has been changed recently, the link now is: https://repo.spring.io/ui/repos/tree/General/release%2Forg%2Fspringframework%2Fspring

Answer (score 5):

Important points to understand in all the spring related repo is that it contains 3 zip files .

1. **spring-framework-{version}-dist.zip** : contains all the spring
   related jars.
2. **spring-framework-{verison}-docs.zip** : contains all the standard documents in HTML format for spring and related java api documents. It is similar to Oracle API Documentation. 
   **Note : Inside all the folders you will find and index.html file. U can consume it typing the folder path till index.html in web browser.
3. **spring-framework-{version}-schema.zip***: contains all the spring modules based standard xsd for xml based spring development.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue and I followed  Brian Clozel advice above.

1. Create a new Maven project in eclipse.
2. Edit the pom.xml and add the Spring dependencies as follows -

   org.springframework
       spring-core
       5.0.6.RELEASE

When you build the project in eclipse,it hits the maven repo and downloads the requisite spring jars for you. The indirect dependencies should also be downloaded automatically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Place this URL in browser

https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/spring/

Step 2) Scroll down & select latest version. Example : 5.3.9/

Step 3) Click on the file similar to "spring-5.3.9-dist.zip" to download

Step 4) Hence JAR files of latest spring is downloaded in zip format.